# Reading data from a CSV file yields TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, csv

I have a csv file with the following data stored as uncov_users.csv: `2867,2978`

I am trying to get the data from the CSV file and print it but I am getting an error. I need the data in separate variables so I am using the `for i,j` loop.

My Code:

```
import numpy as np
uncov_users = np.genfromtxt('ucov_users.csv', delimiter=',')
for i,j in uncov_users:
    ux_coor = i  
    uy_coor = j  
    print(ux_coor,uy_coor)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programmes\Final_Year\Plot_DFO\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    for i, j in uncov_users:
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.float64 object
```

I am just trying to understand what is wrong with it and how can it be fixed.

Comment: Your code should work as it is. Does the input file only have a single row? If not can you paste a bit more of the input file?

Comment: @ephsmith all I have in my input file is ```2216,572
2308,760
1563,1242``` two numbers in each line (x and y coordinates) separated by a comma and a blank line in the end

Comment: @aniket32 Just to be sure those values are seperated by new lines('\n') not spaces right? Because I just replicated your error by not using new lines to seperate those tuples. Make sure to have each tuple in a new line. [Like this](https://i.imgur.com/OF4igGv.png), [not like this](https://i.imgur.com/WiyrMIB.png).

Comment: @3nws Yes, I have the values in separate lines, not all together, [like this](https://imgur.com/a/xQ6t1Ew)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

text = open("ucov_users.csv", "r")
text = ''.join([i for i in text]) \
    .replace(" ", "\n")
x = open("ucov_users.csv", "w")
x.writelines(text)
x.close()


uncov_users = np.genfromtxt('ucov_users.csv', delimiter=',')
for i,j in uncov_users:
    ux_coor = i  
    uy_coor = j  
    print(ux_coor,uy_coor)
```

Comment: I see what you are trying to do, have the data in each line and not all together, but my data is in each line [my data](https://imgur.com/a/xQ6t1Ew), but I still don't know why my solution is not working, but your solution works, so I am guessing I must have made some formatting error while storing the data in the CSV file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas. You can put you csv in a dataframe, then convert you columns into numpy arrays :

```py
import pandas
import numpy as np

dataframe = pandas.read_csv('ucov_users.csv', delimiter=',')
ux_coord = np.array(dataframe.iloc[:, 0])
uy_coord = np.array(dataframe.iloc[:, 1])
```

Comment: Its returning empty two arrays, ```[][]```

Answer (score 0):

Your `uncov_users` variable is the wrong shape. For the loop

```py
for i,j in uncov_users:
   # stuff ...
```

to work, `uncov_users` would need to be a 2d array with two columns, so that `i` could be assigned a value from the first column and `j` a value from the second column.

This problem would be easier to see if you rewrote your `for` loop like this:

```py
for row in uncov_users:
   i,j = row
   # stuff ...
```

For the `uncov_users` array that you have, `row` is just a number (or to be precise, a `numpy.float64` object), so it can't be unpacked. It doesn't have two components that could be assigned to the variables `i` and `j`.

Probably the simplest way to fix this would be to use the `numpy.atleast_2d()` function, e.g,

```py
uncov_users = np.atleast_2d(np.genfromtxt('ucov_users.csv', delimiter=','))
```

This way, if the file `ucov_users.csv` has only one row with two columns, the array `uncov_users` will still have two columns, instead of being a 1d array with two elements. (Of course, this assumes that `ucov_users.csv` always has two columns.)